# decoding a nested array in swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

take the following JSON:

```
let rawJson =
"""
[
      {
          "id": 1,
          "name":"John Doe"
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "name":"Luke Smith"
      },
 ]
"""
```

and `User` model:

```
struct User: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

It's pretty simple to decode, like so:

```
let data = rawJson.data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let users = try! decoder.decode([User].self, from: data!)
```

But what if the JSON looks like this, where the top level is a dictionary and  need to fetch the array of `users`:

```
let json =
"""
{
    "users":
    [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name":"John Doe"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name":"Luke Smith"
        },
    ]
}
"""
```

What's the most effective solution to reading the JSON? I could definitely create another `struct` like this:

```
struct SomeStruct: Decodable {
    var posts: [Post]
}
```

and decode like so:

```
let users = try! decoder.decode(SomeStruct.self, from: data!)
```

but it doesn't feel right doing it that way, creating a new model object just because the array is nested inside a dictionary.

Comment: Check this article under the "wrapper keys" heading. It appears this is the correct way to parse that structure out. http://benscheirman.com/2017/06/ultimate-guide-to-json-parsing-with-swift-4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to take advantage of `JSONDecoder` you have to create a nested struct(ure).

I recommend to use the name `Root` for the root object and put the child struct into `Root`

```
struct Root : Decodable {

    struct User : Decodable {
        let id: Int
        let name: String
    }

    let users : [User]
}

let json = """
{
    "users": [{"id": 1, "name":"John Doe"},
              {"id": 2, "name":"Luke Smith"}]
}
"""

let data = Data(json.utf8)
do {
    let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(root.users)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: There is no need to have the User  struct nested into it the Root struct  `struct User : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
struct Root : Decodable {
    let users : [User]
}` The result would be the same

Comment: Yes there is no need, but if the struct is not used somewhere else it's cleaner (imho) and it illustrates the equivalent of the JSON structure.