# Swift - nested array to json

Tags: arrays, json, swift, objectmapper

I'm using ObjectMapper convert object to Json, and I need to send an array of an object containing arrays. I'm using .toJsonArray() to convert an array of simple objects. But now I have nested array, my class is like:

```
class Organizer {
   var id = -1
   var firstParty:FirstParty?
   var secondParty:[SecondParty]?
   var generalInfo:[GeneralInfo]?
}
```

And I have to send an array of organizer through API, any advise?

Thank you

Comment: Use native `Codable`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46670523/10549967

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseRequest<T> : ObjectMapper{
   var nameofyourarray : [T]?
}
```

Use this patter you will be able to send array of organizer to server
Then

You will need to convert this array to string or in json format, whatever your server accepts. you can google it.